# Ring-LWE lattice cryptography and FFT Trick for $X^n+1$

Tags: lattice-crypto

in reference [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/039.pdf) the FFT trick for $X^n+1$ is discussed with reference to the Number Theoretic transformation. On page 5, the Chinese Remainder Theorem is used to define the mapping.

[image]

So far so good. But I am particularly interested in how to arrive at the statement that on the k-th level we have the following relationship:

[image]

Where $i = 0,...,2^k-1$. Here $\text{brv}$ maps an $log(n)$-bit number to its bitreversal, $brv(b_{log(n)−1}2^{log(n)−1} + · · · + b_1 2 + b_0) = b_0 2^{ log(n)−1} + · · · + b_{log(n)−2}2 + b_{log(n)−1}$.

I cannot deduce from the text how to arrive at the expression in the exponent $\text{brv}(2^k+i)$. That is the reason for my question, how exactly do you arrive at the exponent here?

Comment: Please edit into question to make it self contained: here brv maps an log(n)-bit number to its bitreversal,
brv(blog(n)−12
log(n)−1 + · · · + b12 + b0) = b02
log(n)−1 + · · · + blog(n)−22 + blog(n)−1.

Answer (score 2):

It's first worth clarifying that your question has nothing (directly) to do with cryptography, and instead is entirely a question about how the FFT works.
The map

$$f\mapsto (f\bmod X^{n/2}-\zeta^{n/2}, f\bmod X^{n/2}+\zeta^{n/2})$$

is typically called a ["butterfly"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_diagram) (though often $\zeta$ is a root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
This difference doesn't really matter).
Bit reversal appears when one studies the [inplace Cooley-Tukey FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm#Data_reordering,_bit_reversal,_and_in-place_algorithms) in particular.
So to understand this you can look for any explanation of the (inplace) Cooley-Tukey FFT.
See for example [this random website I found](https://vanhunteradams.com/FFT/FFT.html#Single-point-transforms-as-reordering), though if you want something else the thing to search on is "inplace Cooley-Tukey", perhaps with "bit reversal" thrown in there.

At this point it is worth clarifying the one point here that *is* of cryptographic relevance.
The inplace Cooley-Tukey FFT $\mathcal{F}_{\mathsf{CT}}$ can be decomposed into

1. A bunch of computations of butterflies, which I will call $\mathcal{B}$, followed by
2. a bit-reversal permutation to "fix" that the outputs being in the wrong order, which I will call $\sigma$.

This is to say that

$$\mathcal{F}_{\mathsf{CT}}(x) = (\sigma\circ \mathcal{B})(x).$$

Some schemes (namely Kyber/ML-KEM) choose to omit $\sigma$.
This is to say that they leave their FFT domain values "in the wrong order", and $\mathcal{F}_{\mathsf{Kyber}} = \mathcal{B}$.
This has some benefits when it comes to AVX implementations of the FFT, but does mean that the FFT in Kyber is not *exactly* the same as a standard FFT, both because

1. it is done over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ rather than $\mathbb{C}$ (this requires $p$ to be NTT friendly, but besides that is standard/boring), and
2. the output is (not) permuted by $\sigma$.

---

**Some more details**:

One way of viewing the FFT is linear algebraically.
The following is from [Tolimieri et al., "Algorithms for Discrete Fourier Transform and Convolution"](https://ece.uprm.edu/%7Edomingo/inel8396/TOLIMIERI%20-%20Algorithms%20for%20Discrete%20Fourier%20Transform%20and%20Convolution%20(1989).pdf), section 4.

The DFT is linear on a finite-dimensional space, and so can be written as a matrix multiplication.
One can write an $N = 2M$ dimensional DFT as

$$F_{N} = P_N(I_2\otimes F_M)T_N(F_2\otimes I_M)$$

Here, $A\otimes B$ is the [kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of matrices, $T_N$ is the matrix of "twiddle factors", and $P_N$ is the matrix such that $P_N(A\otimes B) = B\otimes A$.

Anyway, applying the above relation a few times, one can find (Theorem 1) that if $N = 2^k$

$$
F_N = Q_N\prod_{i = 1}^k(I_{2^{i-1}}\otimes T_{2^{k-i+1}})\otimes (I_{2^{i-1}}\otimes F_2\otimes I_{2^{k-1}})
$$

Note that the kronecker product $A\otimes B$ satisfies the "mixed-product property" $(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D) = (AC)\otimes (BC)$, at least when the matrix sizes match up.
One also has that $I_{2^k} = I_2\otimes I_{2^{k-1}} = I_{2^{k-1}}\otimes I_2$.

Here, one can compute that

$$Q_N = P_N(I_2\otimes P_{N/2})\dots (I_{N/4}\otimes P_4)$$

All that remains is to show that $Q_N$ is actually bit reversal.
This is done in discussion around eq. 19 in the source.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your reply and your efforts! I would agree with what you say. But: For me, this does not yet conclusively clarify how to apply this to my question. For me, the aspect that explains how the exponent $\text{brv}(2^k+i)$ is obtained is still missing.

Comment: @TreeBook1 the link "random website that I found" goes through a worked example for $N = 2^3$, though for FFTs over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @TreeBook1 you can also view this (linear)-algebraically. See example [section 4 of "Algorithms for Discrete Fourier Transform and Convolution" by Tolimieri et. al](https://ece.uprm.edu/~domingo/inel8396/TOLIMIERI%20-%20Algorithms%20for%20Discrete%20Fourier%20Transform%20and%20Convolution%20(1989).pdf), which includes a derivation where bit reversal pops out.

Comment: Thanks for the references! Quick note, I know that the indices of the coefficients follow the bit reversal. This is also shown by the formula in your first source $(f_0 + ... f_4) + ... + (f_3 + ... f_7)$. But: How the exponent is then explained, from my source, is not yet completely transparent. Let me take a look at your second source.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Tolimieri's book