# NTT implementation using matrix multiplication

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

I am trying to implement the NTT as done in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.14191.pdf), but I keep getting the wrong result even when doing the math by hand. Is formula 9 of the paper wrong ? (I suspect that I am the wrong one but just want to confirm)

Comment: You might find the second half of the answer to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/109841/ring-lwe-lattice-cryptography-and-fft-trick-for-xn1/109844#109844) (and the provided source) useful.